# Can any current hardware set a RAM page to be executable but not readable?

Tags: security, memory, dep

Just like how NX / DEP allow a page to be set non executable when it is writable, is it possible to tell the CPU that it can execute a page (i.e. read it for instruction fetch) but throw and exception if it is accessed via a mov instruction? The effect will be to make it impossible / very hard to copy the binary data of the instructions just by misusing an exploit.

The possible use I thought something like this might have was in preventing an exploit disclosing the contents of the executable pages, making ROP attacks harder. ([this paper](http://cs.unc.edu/~fabian/papers/oakland2013.pdf) kind of makes it seem like all ASLR is just a bandage on a hemorrhage) There are a huge number of ways to trick programs into reading arbitrary memory locations, and patching them all will be a hopeless task.